# Define javascript parameter in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

During a while loop in PHP I want to create following link:

```
echo '<a onclick="getSolution('.ResultArray['qid'].')" style="color: red;">L&ouml;sung anzeigen</a>';
```

But there it is a mistake. It will not take the **$ResultArray['qid']** as a parameter for the javascript function. I need this parameter for define which div it has to take when clicking on the link.

---

Here you get the complete while loop in php:

```
while($ResultArray = mysqli_fetch_array($getQuestions)) {
    echo '<p>';
    echo $ResultArray['question'];
    echo '<br />';          
            echo '<input type="text" style="width: 500px;"/>';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<a onclick="getSolution('.ResultArray['qid'].')" style="color: red;">L&ouml;sung anzeigen</a>';
    echo '<div id="'.$ResultArray['qid'].'" style="visibility: hidden">';
    echo $ResultArray['answer'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

---

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Step one: [Enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393)

Comment: I get following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in ... /example.php on line 135

Comment: Step two: fix it. If the ID is a text, then you are missing quotes. Also missing the dollar sign ($).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to reference your `ResultArray` variable without prefacing it with your `$` symbol.

Corrected:

```
echo '<a onclick="getSolution('.$ResultArray['qid'].')" style="color: red;">L&ouml;sung anzeigen</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a stupid mistake. I haven't seen it. But thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<a onclick="getSolution('.ResultArray['qid'].')"
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^---undefined constant, since it has no "$"
```

You must have `$ResultArray` in there. Without the `$`, it's a constant, and you cannot have constant arrays.

Comment: Thank you. That's a stupid mistake. I haven't seen it. But thank you very much.